# Page won't redirect when uploading to db with multer

Tags: redirect, next.js, multer

I'm trying to upload (update acutally) an image to a db and then redirect to profile page, i tried everything and the photo is updated successfully in the db but page wont redirect.

- **If i dont attach an image everything is ok and user gets redirected.**
- **If i do attach an image user just stays on form page, no errors pop up, page just gets refreshed (photo gets updated in db successfully)**

---

- post route

```
var store = require("./multer");
router.post("/:username/edit", isUser, personalContent, store.single("profilePic"), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (req.file) {
            await User.updateOne(
                { username: req.user.username },
                {
                    username: req.params.username,
                    dateOfBirth: req.body.date,
                    filename: req.file.originalname,
                    contentType: req.file.mimetype,
                    imageBase64: fs.readFileSync(req.file.path).toString("base64"),
                },
                { upsert: true }
            );
        } else {
            await User.updateOne(
                { username: req.user.username },
                {
                    username: req.params.username,
                    dateOfBirth: req.body.date,
                },
                { upsert: true }
            );
        }
        res.redirect("/profile/" + req.params.username + "?msg=Profile updated successfully");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/profile/" + req.params.username + "?msg=Error while updating profile");
    }
});
```

- ejs form

```
<form action="/profile/<%= user.username %>/edit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <% if(error){ %> <%= error %> <% } %> <% if(msg){ %> <%= msg %> <% } %>
    <div>
        <label for="username">Username: </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<%= user.username %>" disabled />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="date">Date of birth: </label>
        <input type="date" name="date" required value="<%= user.dateOfBirth.toISOString().split("T")[0] %>" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="profpic">Profile picture:</label>
        <input type="file" name="profilePic" />
        <div>
            <% if(user.imageBase64){ %>
            <img src="data:<%=user.contentType%>;base64,<%=user.imageBase64%>" alt="" style="height: 3rem" />
            <% }else{ %> Add profile picture <% } %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

- multer.js

```
const multer = require("multer");
//set storage
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "uploads");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now());
    },
});

module.exports = store = multer({ storage: storage });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with LiveServer chrome extension, it was messing something up with redirects. Now this question seems stupid to me but if someone stumbled upon this I hope I could help

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33248464)

Comment: well this resolved this issue so why isnt it an answer?

Comment: Fair point. Honestly, I'm just learning the ropes with my recently elevated mod privileges. Trying to figure out this "review queue" thing.